# loop issue with large data php

Tags: php

i have list of ids in txt file i use `while` to Looping and it works good with
small amount of ids but with 5k ids take 5 minutes to do and i get `echo` three time 
i think the issue with apache2.conf is there any setting Cause this?

*Simple example*

```
$data= fopen( "list.txt", "r");
$a= 0;
$b= 0;

while( !feof( $data)) {
    $id = fgets( $data);
    $ok =  // Do something
    if($ok == false ){
        $a++;
    }else{
        $b++;
    }
}

echo "$a - $b";
```

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: I am no php expert but in the // do something you probably request your database since you are loading IDs. 5k int should be no issue. The issue is in your do something code, post it.

Comment: You can verify where the problem is by commenting out the line `$ok =  // Do something` and replacing it with something like `$ok = true;` and see how it performs then.

Comment: @Poutrathor its request to telegram api

Comment: @NigelRen Works normally because it doesn't take long that's why I think the problem is in apache2.conf

Answer (score -1):

You should not called an api outside your program 5000 times and more in one big loop. Apache is fine, your software needs to be restructured.

Try to send batch calls of 500 by 500.

Edit: please contribute to the post while down voting.

Imho, you should write it like this :

- Read N numbers of lines , N being a value that you will find works best in your use case (try 1000, 500, 100, 50, 10, etc.)
- Save that IDs in a stream/array/list, whatever structure works best.
- start a job with this first N IDs
- Keep reading the lines
- Start another job once the next N lines are read
- Until end of lines
- Meanwhile, the jobs will call the Telegram API to do whatever you try to do.

Remember that when calling an API outside your server, like you do by calling Telegram (for a bot maybe?), you have to manage web issues (time out, API's limits since most API do not allow free users to send thousands of requests in a few instants and more).

good luck